# Drupal article verification by admin and verified article to be read

Tags: drupal

I am a newbie to drupal development and trying to create a magazine site using drupal. I have a functionality like their should be a separate POST menu where users post and that article should be going to Admin page. Once he verifies it, it should be visible in the READ menu. Please help me.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @MatthewDean Apologies for the mistake but my question is which modules will allow me to setup the mentioned functionality? how to restrict the other users from reading the articles which are being posted under POST menu? My specification is that only the admin of the site should be able to view the articles posted

Answer (score 0):

go to book using drupal it contains example  of trigger and action like which you want for that u should  use trigger and action module